ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config' gunicorn
I'm trying to run a django project on docker
project
├── manage.py
├── config
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── ...
├──__init__.py
Dockerfile
docker-compose.yml
entrypoint.sh

Dockerfile
...

WORKDIR /app

...
COPY project project 

EXPOSE 8000

COPY entrypoint.sh ./entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod a+x ./entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]

docker-compose.yml
version: '3.9'

services:
...
  web:
   build: .
   container_name: web
   restart: unless-stopped
   ports:
     - '8000:8000'
   depends_on:
     - db
...

entrypoint.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

RUN_MANAGE_PY='poetry run python project/manage.py'


echo 'Collect static files...'
$RUN_MANAGE_PY collectstatic --no-input

echo 'Running migrations...'
$RUN_MANAGE_PY migrate --no-input

echo 'Starting server...'
exec poetry run gunicorn project.config.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000

wsgi.py
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()

when I run the command docker-compose up I get an error
web    | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config
web    | [2024-04-12 20:07:47 +0600] [15] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 15)
web    | [2024-04-12 20:07:47 +0600] [1] [ERROR] Worker (pid:15) exited with code 3
web    | [2024-04-12 20:07:47 +0600] [1] [ERROR] Shutting down: Master
web    | [2024-04-12 20:07:47 +0600] [1] [ERROR] Reason: Worker failed to boot.

collectstatic and migrate are successful
I tried changing the gunicorn command to ... gunicorn project/config.wsgi:application ... I also tried removing the project from the command and tried ... gunicorn wsgi:application... but still got the same error
I have no experience with gunicorn and docker, so any help would be appreciated

You need to add the project directory to your python path. PYTHONPATH="project". Python is using the incorrect pythonpath as its directory.

Assuming that your project looks like this:
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── entrypoint.sh
├── project
│   ├── config
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   └── manage.py
└── pyproject.toml

Using same entrypoint.sh as in question.
 docker-compose.yml
version: '3.9'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: web
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'

  database:
    image: postgres:16
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=movies_database
      - POSTGRES_USER=app
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123qwe

 Dockerfile (There were lots of details missing from the Dockerfile provided in the question, but assuming that it looks something like this. The important thing for resolving the packages was to set PYTHONPATH to /app/project).
FROM python:3.10-bookworm

WORKDIR /app

ENV POETRY_VERSION=1.8.1
ENV POETRY_VENV=/app/.venv

ENV PYTHONPATH=/app/project

ENV PATH="${POETRY_VENV}/bin:${PATH}:"

RUN python -m venv $POETRY_VENV && \
    pip install -U pip setuptools && \
    pip install poetry==${POETRY_VERSION}

COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock* ./

RUN poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true && \
    poetry install --no-root

COPY project project

COPY entrypoint.sh ./entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod a+x ./entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]

